# Creating Virtual host on Websphere

Tags: web-applications, websphere, port, virtual-hosts

Websphere allows virtual hosts to be created. I can also map any number of host aliases (host name and port) to the virtual host.

Does this mean that Websphere starts listening on all those ports for HTTP requests? If not, what is the reason for mapping the port number for virtual host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebSphere doesn't start listening on these ports.
You define port number in the virtual host, if your front end server is listening on non default port and is routing requests to WebSphere.

For example, if your Apache would listen on :81 and :444 port and route requests to your application, without defining new host aliases in default_host you would get Error 500 - virtual host/ webgroup not found, as it wouldn't be configure to accept requests going on these ports.

Comment: The frontend server can be on different machine right? And then the WAS plugin should be installed on the frontend server?

Comment: @Teddy Correct. It can be local or remote, but you always install plugin where the web server is. Usually it is on remote machine, for example in the DMZ.